# Comparator using only XOR

Tags: bitwise-operators, xor

I would like to ask how to make a 2 bit comparator using only the XOR gate to check if the numbers are equal

is it possible to build such a comparator?? Od yes, how IT should look?

I tried to create gates: NOT, OR, AND using XOR, but it doesn't seem possible to me

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: You can create a NOT gate using XOR (by 1). Other than that, no because XOR is linear.

Comment: Here's a longer answer about why you can't create AND or OR gates from XOR: [Construct an AND gate from XOR gates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/140684/299558)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create an equality comparison operator from XOR gates.  You have two inputs - let's call them A and B: your XOR operations ultimately operate on number of copies of A and some number of copies of B.  The order in which the XORs are done is irrelevant, as the XOR operation is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).  Basically, if you have an even number of copies of A, they all cancel out and leave you with false/0.  Ditto for B.  So no matter how you arrange copies of A and B inputs and XOR gates, it will boil down to the equivalent of A XOR 0 (which is just A), or A XOR A (which is always 0 and tells you nothing about A), or A XOR B, or B XOR B, or B XOR 0.

As you found, it's similarly impossible to generate a NOT, OR or AND operation.

Comment: `A XOR 1` is logically equivalent to `NOT A`, but I agree with the rest of the conclusion

Comment: @Dash: I'm not sure if "a 2 bit comparator using only the XOR gate" allows a hardcoded "1" input in OP's context, but good to have your comment so it can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just assume you can use `a XOR 1` == `NOT a` to provide a more useful answer.

Then you can build comparators:

`a!=b`: `a XOR b`
`a==b`: `NOT a XOR b` (read that as you like)
which is the same as `1 XOR a XOR b`

The rest (`>`, `>=`) cannot be built because `XOR` is commutative, as mentioned. This essentially means you cannot distinguish between `a XOR b` and `b XOR a` which in turn means you can't say whether `a is greater than b` or `b is greater than a`.